# When does the public beta phase begin?

Tags: discussion

I think it was supposed to start a week after private beta opened. It's been about that long. When does public beta open or has it already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In about two hours (as of this post). By time you read this, the public beta will have likely already started. Public beta starts 7 days after launch. For reference, you can always track a site's progress in Area 51 (http://area51.stackexchange.com).

[Ubuntu's progress](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7716/ubuntu):

Comment: OT: I can't believe SE uses the Impact font. :D

Answer (score 1):

In about 2 hours see also [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7716/ubuntu). Public beta always starts 7 days after the begin of the private beta.

Answer (score 0):

it is live now,woohooo